# Python calls a Dll which is written in C and contains Pythoncode

Tags: python, c, multithreading, dll, ctypes

my Problem is:
I call a DLL in Python like:

```
from ctypes import *
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary(str(path_to_dll))
mydll.python_test()
```

if I call a function which is written in C it is executed without any problems.
BUT if i use embedded Python code in the dll like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int python_test()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print 'hello'");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 1;
}
```

The Python-Interpreter gives me this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "W:\rin83wi\Python_test\batching_DLL.py", line 43, in <module>
  mydll.python_test()
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000008
```

if I use the embedded Python function inside of an C-Console-Application it works fine.

After looking up a little bit I got these ideas:

- Make additional python threads -> failed
- Make additional C threads -> faild (thread creating following this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx only adding the embedded Python code in the created thread
- child prozess (not tested yet)
- calling a .exe which calls the dll or something else (but how is the communication working?) (not tested yet)

I'm working with:

Visualstudio 10 (VS13 is also available)

Python 2.7.11

IDE for Python is Anaconda (Spyder)

The problem seems to be that only one instance of Python is able to run.

Comment: C modules in Python shouldn't call Py_Initialize out finalize since the interpreter already exists (and should exist afterwards to continue running). You're basically embedding a Python interpreter in a running Python executable which is weird. Just write a standard Python module - the documentation for that is pretty good.

Comment: II know it's wierd to call a dll in Python and in the dll Pythoncode is called but I need it...
so if I call the function Python_test with only `PyRun_SimpleString("print 'hello'");` without Py_Initialise I get the Windows error    

If I call it in a seperat C Thread Python.exe simply doesn't work any more with no special error message. but "hello" is printed before it breaks down

Comment: Is there maybe a Flag or something else which must be set or cleared? or is there maybe a problem with the Paths or something else? Would it be better to code in simple files and muild it with gcc instead of msbuild / VS10?